# creating HTTP persistent connection, to create 'smooth' data over GSM sending

Tags: gsm, http, datalogging, tcpip, iot

**Project goals**

- Send data over GSM to firebase
- Fast sampling - need to send 16 bytes every half second to firebase
- Send data using GET or POST to server with PHP script, that redirect data to firebase

**Problems -- 
Extremely low data rate!**

- Using standard GET or POST request from client(arduino) side, is impossible to achieve second (2) project goal.
- **To send data correctly I need to close connection with server, so next data package unfortunately waits(2-6 seconds) for establishing a new connection.**

  Is this quite nonsense? I'm using ArduinoHttpClient library.

**My actual Nonsense Connection and fully useless, but works**

```cpp
while(1){

http.post("/test.php","application/x-www-form-urlencoded","data=0");
http.stop(); //closing connection with server

//next instruction take over 5 second to establish new connection :(

http.post("/test.php","application/x-www-form-urlencoded","data=0");
http.stop(); //closing connection with server, whyyy?
}
```

Data are send once per 2 - 6 seconds, this is not even funny. NEED to send data every 0.5 seconds!

So I decided to create super solution, which not works :C

```cpp
while(1){ 
    http.post("/test.php","application/x-www-form-urlencoded","data=0");
    delay(xxx);
//no connection closing, no wasting time for establishing new one :)
}
```

Just tell my why this connection is not "Keep-Alive", also used with

> http.sendHeader("Connection: Keep-Alive"); or
>   http.connectionKeepAlive();

```cpp
//First run
http.post(blabla);// returns value: 0 & data are logged into firebase
//Second run
http.post(blabla);// returns value: -2 & data are not logged in firebase
```

**my test.php file**

```cpp
<?php
require_once 'firebaseLib.php';
$url = 'https://czujniki-aa5ca.firebaseio.com/';
// --- Use your token from Firebase here
$token = ':-CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC';

$arduino_data_post = $_POST['data'];
$firebasePath = '/';

$fb = new fireBase($url, $token);
$response = $fb->push($firebasePath, $arduino_data_post);
sleep(2);
```

Comment: does the 'modem' disconnect from network with no active connection? search for a setting to keep the GPRS connection connected

Comment: @Juraj i think modem doesn't turn off networking itself, I will check the code and post back. If it will not work, i will test it on pure AT commands.

Comment: try in the library in HttpClient.h make resetState() public (by moving 'protected:') and then in sketch call resetState() before post()

Comment: @Juraj [link] (https://ibb.co/7rc2Yt8) look at the screenshot. resetState() is working fine, and now we dont need to use stop(), but essentially it works like .stop(); Look at the timestamp, delay between data uploading is still awful. 0 means 0 error code, so data are send successfully

Answer (score 1):

The ArduinoHttpCliemt library's HttpClient.stop() method does two things. It resets the state of the HttpClient object and stops the underlying Client connection (TCP connection). If HttpClient.stop() is not called, the internal state is not good to call get() or post() again.

The method resetState() is called in HttpClient.stop() to reset the internal state of the HttpClient object. But resetState() is protected. To call it we must modify the library header file.

In HttpClient.h make resetState() public (by moving 'protected:') and then in sketch call resetState() before post(). It will put the HttpClient object into initial state without disconnecting the underlying TCP connection.

Comment: Yes that's work, but time between POST's is still huge. [link] (ibb.co/7rc2Yt8) screenshot

Comment: add `#define LOGGING` at the beginning of HttpClient.cpp, to see if it uses the connection or reconnects

Comment: [link] (https://ibb.co/k88TXXm) logging returns: connection already open, connected. Look at time, delay increases while new posts are sended. Is it opening new connections, instead of using first one?

Comment: no it always prints Connected. so it is reusing the connection. that was your question. the request takes time, not the connection.

Comment: try to read the response with `int statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();`

Comment: [link] (https://ibb.co/Q9ZHxJN), with responseStatusCode(); arduino client do nothing

Comment: so it doesn't get a response. check the server

Comment: [link] (https://ibb.co/gJxQSfw) now i setted it to make reconnect every POST. And it seems to be paradox, because we got smaller delays, if you look at the timestamp. Quite frustrating, keep-alive should lower time between requests, but it's working in the opposite direction

Comment: because not the new connection is the problem as you can see on the output times